# how to serialize an object of android.graphics.Path

Tags: android, serialization, memory, path, internal

I'm trying to store objects of Android.graphics.Path in internal device memory. Does anyone know how to serialize a android.graphics.Path object? And also, is there any other way of storing a Path object? Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

The way I did it is to identify the methods that I needed from the original Path class and then simply override those methods as follows:

```
public class CustomPath extends Path implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5974912367682897467L;

private ArrayList<PathAction> actions = new ArrayList<CustomPath.PathAction>();

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    in.defaultReadObject();
    drawThisPath();
}

@Override
public void moveTo(float x, float y) {
    actions.add(new ActionMove(x, y));
    super.moveTo(x, y);
}

@Override
public void lineTo(float x, float y){
    actions.add(new ActionLine(x, y));
    super.lineTo(x, y);
}

private void drawThisPath(){
    for(PathAction p : actions){
        if(p.getType().equals(PathActionType.MOVE_TO)){
            super.moveTo(p.getX(), p.getY());
        } else if(p.getType().equals(PathActionType.LINE_TO)){
            super.lineTo(p.getX(), p.getY());
        }
    }
}

public interface PathAction {
    public enum PathActionType {LINE_TO,MOVE_TO};
    public PathActionType getType();
    public float getX();
    public float getY();
}

public class ActionMove implements PathAction, Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7198142191254133295L;

    private float x,y;

    public ActionMove(float x, float y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public PathActionType getType() {
        return PathActionType.MOVE_TO;
    }

    @Override
    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

}

public class ActionLine implements PathAction, Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8307137961494172589L;

    private float x,y;

    public ActionLine(float x, float y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public PathActionType getType() {
        return PathActionType.LINE_TO;
    }

    @Override
    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

}
}
```

In my example I need "moveTo" and "lineTo", so in this case I simply hold the drawing information in a list. This list contains the drawing information (what I call "action") needed by Path in order to restore the drawing as it looked like before the object was serialized. Then when I deserialize my objects of type CustomPath i make sure to let [the default serialization protocol](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) call "drawThisPath", so the path is redrawn.

Comment: Good approach. I just prettified your code. My variant here http://pastebin.com/CtJ5ibA7

Comment: When I save Custom Path in file, kill app then open it path became empty.
Path is not null but actions are empty and I cant redraw it.

Answer (score 5):

I've just managed to solve this.  My application is based off the FingerPaintDemo, so makes use of just moveTo and quadTo, but I think you can apply this approach to any Path functions.

First, extend Path as follows:

```
import android.graphics.Path;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class SerializablePath extends Path implements Serializable {

    private ArrayList<float[]> pathPoints;

    public SerializablePath() {
        super();
        pathPoints = new ArrayList<float[]>();
    }

    public SerializablePath(SerializablePath p) {
        super(p);
        pathPoints = p.pathPoints;
    }

    public void addPathPoints(float[] points) {
        this.pathPoints.add(points);
    }

    public void loadPathPointsAsQuadTo() {
        float[] initPoints = pathPoints.remove(0);
        this.moveTo(initPoints[0], initPoints[1]);
        for (float[] pointSet : pathPoints) {
            this.quadTo(pointSet[0], pointSet[1], pointSet[2], pointSet[3]);
        } 
    }
}
```

I don't think I need to paste the implementation code, but if you want to see it let me know.  Basically just as you call something like myPath.quadTo(x1, y1, x2, y2), also call myPath.addPathPoints(new float[]{x1, y1, x2, y2}).

Serialize the object to disk as normal, and when you read it back in, just be sure to call myPath.loadPathPointsAsQuadTo().

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at this, but see if this helps: https://gist.github.com/2050745

Comment: @KazekageGaara brk3 has already mentioned that, you need to call myPath.loadPathPointsAsQuadTo() to restore the de-serialized path.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing so special for Path Class. Use can serialize any class that implements the Serializable interface..

#### Serializable interface is a Marker interface. i.e it dont have any method to implement. It just signify that the object can be deflatted to files/Memroies and later can be inflatted to be a live object again

What you do just make a class that extends your android.graphics.Path class and implements the Serializable interface. Then use this class instead of your android.graphics.Path. Then you will be able to apply serialization over it.

And check the following link for a detailed information

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It seems, after deserialization Path object is empty, e.g. without any lines and curves. I think, Path object is a container of lines, rectangles, arcs objects and they should be Serializable too. If I right, Path serialization have no sense... Please, correct me anyone :)

Comment: Unfortunately Javanator's approach doesn't work, the code will serialize but the Path is empty when reading it back in.  Could really use some other ideas as Im stuck with the exact same problem.

Comment: It's impossible: Path is just a wrapper around a native path in Skia, which can't be extracted