# Handwriting Recognition Application in Android

Tags: android

I'm working on a application for handwriting recognition,ie, the user draws their character into the screen,and then that particular alphabet is generated automatically.

The approach I'm taking(after a reading from [here](http://drdobbs.com/security/184408923?pgno=2)),is to first train the system. While training, I store the Path([android.graphics.Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html)) values. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919740/how-to-serialize-an-object-of-android-graphics-path), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832931/can-i-serialize-the-paths-drawn-on-canvas-for-redrawing-the-paths-on-relaunch-of) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243181/how-to-store-object-in-sqlite-database), I know how to serialize and store the Path values to a database during the training phase.

Now while comparing the values for comparison with what the user has drawn as a character, I can increase the accuracy by calculating the centroid and the number of strokes of every character,to differentiate between cases like `b` and `d`.

The problem I'm facing is :

[image]

The three a's written on the screen are all different, and will all generate a different Path value. How do I compare such characters?

Now,I know there are many such questions on SO regarding handwriting recognition. But since I have already taken up an approach, I don't think those questions would be relevant to me. But if anyone has better and easier solutions to handwriting recognition,can feel free to suggest. :-)