# Convert android.graphics.Path object to byte[] and back

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to convert an `android.graphics.Path` object to `byte[]` so that I could store it  in a blob storage in SQLite, also to convert it back.

So far I don't even know where to begin...

Thanks to anyone willing to help.

Answer (score 2):

As `Path` extends `Object`, you can use something like this:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(path);
    byte[] array = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Since Path is not serializable, trying this will throw a java.io.NotSerializableException: android.graphics.Path

Comment: @jhnewkirk You can [make a serialized class Path](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8127953/2668136) by overriding the methods before the C native methods calls.

Answer (score 1):

Serialize your object and upload that file .

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
out.writeObject(android.graphics.Path);
out.close()
byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();  //byte array
```

to recover that object use deserialization

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buf)); 
      class_name recover =(clas_name) in.readObject(); 
      in.close(); 
      return object;
```

Comment: System.err: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.graphics.Path