# Scale and position a path in a custom View in Android

Tags: android, android-view

I'm using a custom `View` so the user can draw on the screen. I'm using the `Path` class and everything works out.

When the orientation change, the custom `View` width and height changes too. My question would be if there is a way to scale the path according to the new `View` size, and position it relatively too.

**PS:** for anyone wondering how did I save the path for orientation change, all credits to **Rabie Jradi** [how to serialize an object of android.graphics.Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919740/how-to-serialize-an-object-of-android-graphics-path)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to scale path.

`Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();`
`scaleMatrix.postResize(orginalWidth/currentWidth, orginalHeight/currentHeight);`
`path.transform(scaleMatrix);`

Comment: There is no Matrix.postResize() method.  There is a setScale() method.

Comment: Maybe i meant postScale() or API changed in 4 years. Honestly I don't even remember i wrote this.