# Can android.graphics.Path be made Parcelable?

Tags: android, memory, serialization, path, parcelable

I've found a few [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919740/how-to-serialize-an-object-of-android-graphics-path) about making `Path` a `Serializable` object but I couldn't find anything about making it `Parcelable`. From what I've read, `Parcelable` objects are more efficient for packing and unpacking in a `Bundle`.

I've made a new object called `ParcelablePath`, which extends 'Path' and implements `Parcelable` and have overridden the required methods, but I'm not really sure what to do in the overridden methods.

My question is, is it even possible to make `Path` a `Parcelable` object? If so how can I do it?

Here is some sample code:

```
public class ParcelablePath extends Path implements Parcelable {
    protected ParcelablePath(Parcel in) {
    }

    public static final Creator<ParcelablePath> CREATOR = new Creator<ParcelablePath>() {
        @Override
        public ParcelablePath createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ParcelablePath(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ParcelablePath[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ParcelablePath[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    }
}
```

Comment: It may help to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable

Comment: *but I'm not really sure what to do in the overridden methods* save the state :) so you would be able to redo those opperation in readParcel ... the easiest way would be save(put into ArrayList) object which is also parcelable and saves *the method name and params* ... then the Path would save this array to the parcel ... on reading you would recreate this ArrayList and then call all the method by name from Path with given parameters

Comment: look out on pitfalls like:    `public void addOval(RectF oval, Direction dir) {
        addOval(oval.left, oval.top, oval.right, oval.bottom, dir);
    }` .... if you override both `addOval(RectF oval, Direction dir)` and `addOval(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Direction dir)` there will be a problem :) (obviously path would then contains 2 ovals )

Comment: @Morrison Chang, as I said, I know the difference between `Serializable` and `Parcelable`, the problem is the implementation of `Parcelable` and if it's at all possible for this class.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to build a path consisting only of straight lines and marshal it to another process, you can use [`Gesture`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/Gesture).

`Gesture` implements `Parcelable` so can be sent accross process boundaries in a `Parcel` and provides a `toPath` method to construct a `Path` at the other end.

```
// build path
val points = ArrayList<GesturePoint>()
points += GesturePoint(x = 0f, y = 0f, timestamp = 0L)
// make parcelable
val stroke = GestureStroke(points)
val gesture = Gesture().apply { addStroke(stroke) }
// send away
```

You could make this an implementation detail of your `ParcelablePath` which would no longer extend `Path` and only expose `toPath` and a limited subset of the `Path` API.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Android Studio there's a nice plugin which will solve your issue and automate the process for making a class Parcelable.

You can have a look here: [Quickly Create Parcelable Class in Android Studio
Android Tutorials Mobile Development](http://codentrick.com/quickly-create-parcelable-class-in-android-studio/)

Comment: This will not apply here as Path is not a simple container ... also if you take a look at the Path source you will know that it uses native (C/C++) code ...