# Android best way to save & load PATH object.

Tags: java, android, path, save, load

im working on an android app where the user is able to draw onto a canvas.
The userinput is saved inside a Path object, which is than drawn onto the canvas.
What i want to achieve is, that the user can save his drawn input(path object) to    load it later on.
So my question is, what is the best way to persist/save and   later on load a path object in android.
Can i somehow save the path to an xml or database?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `android.graphics.Picture`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the user to be able to load those Paths and reuse them,
then you should be able to [Serializable](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) them with either Java's Serializable interface or your own method of custom saving Path information, from a small google search I found a person who already [implemented that using Serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6643686/5733387)

You can start building your solution from that.

**Saving and Loading (Optional)**

Use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library to turn your CustomPath into a JSON format (String)

> toJson()

and then save it in any way you'd like (locally / on the web), also use that library for parsing a JSON format (String) to your CustomPath

> fromJson()

and...

> **TIP"** if you want to keep your saves very small in memory, you should convert your classes to byte[] and then save them in a format that depends on your requirements (ISO_8859_1 or Base64)