# How to save android.graphics.Path in file?

Tags: android, graphics, path, draw

I use this code to Serialize the android.graphics.Path.
But when I save Path to file and then get form file, the path PathAction are empty and I can't redraw the Path.

How to save android.graphics.Path in file and then get it and redraw ?

[This is serialize code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919740/how-to-serialize-an-object-of-android-graphics-path)

```
public class CustomPath extends Path implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5974912367682897467L;

private ArrayList<PathAction> actions = new ArrayList<CustomPath.PathAction>();

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    in.defaultReadObject();
    drawThisPath();
}

@Override
public void moveTo(float x, float y) {
    actions.add(new ActionMove(x, y));
    super.moveTo(x, y);
}

@Override
public void lineTo(float x, float y){
    actions.add(new ActionLine(x, y));
    super.lineTo(x, y);
}

private void drawThisPath(){
    for(PathAction p : actions){
        if(p.getType().equals(PathActionType.MOVE_TO)){
            super.moveTo(p.getX(), p.getY());
        } else if(p.getType().equals(PathActionType.LINE_TO)){
            super.lineTo(p.getX(), p.getY());
        }
    }
}

public interface PathAction {
    public enum PathActionType {LINE_TO,MOVE_TO};
    public PathActionType getType();
    public float getX();
    public float getY();
}

public class ActionMove implements PathAction, Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7198142191254133295L;

    private float x,y;

    public ActionMove(float x, float y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public PathActionType getType() {
        return PathActionType.MOVE_TO;
    }

    @Override
    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

}

public class ActionLine implements PathAction, Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8307137961494172589L;

    private float x,y;

    public ActionLine(float x, float y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public PathActionType getType() {
        return PathActionType.LINE_TO;
    }

    @Override
    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

}
}
```

This is save and get from file

```
public static <T> void saveObjectToFile(Context pContext, T object, final String pFileName) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = pContext.openFileOutput(pFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream of = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            of.writeObject(object);
            of.flush();
            of.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static <T> T getObjectFromFile(Context pContext, final String pFileName) {
        T toReturn = null;
        FileInputStream fis;
        try {
            fis = pContext.openFileInput(pFileName);
            ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            toReturn = (T) oi.readObject();
            oi.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("InternalStorage", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
```

Comment: Do not save the `Path`. Save the instructions needed to rebuild the `Path`, using your own objects and your own persistent data structure.

Comment: If you can put some code example it will be very helpful.
Thank.