# Saving a custom object to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a mini drawing game app and I made this class to save draw Path with their according color, and now I need to save it so that other users of my app can go fetch that data and see the draw in real
`class CustomPath(path: android.graphics.Path, paint: android.graphics.Paint)`
But when I do  `myRefDraw?.push()?.setValue((array))`, where array is a ArrayList I get this error

"E/MessageQueue-JNI: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Serializing Collections is not supported, please use Lists instead"

Is there any better way to save this ArrayList somewhere where the other players of the game could fetch the data it is holding so that the draw appears on their respective screens?

The code:

````
class CanvasView(context: Context, attrs:AttributeSet?): View(context,attrs) {
    private var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private var mFirebaseDatabase:FirebaseDatabase
    var paint: Paint = Paint()
    var path: Path = Path()
    var apagar: Boolean = false

    var array = arrayListOf<CustomPath>()
    private var database: FirebaseDatabase? = null
    private var myRefDraw: DatabaseReference? = null
    var c = CustomPath(path,paint)
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        for (p in array) {
            canvas.drawPath(p.getPath(), p.getPaint())

        }
        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }
    fun clear(){
        array.clear()
        invalidate()
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                path = Path()
                path.moveTo(event.x, event.y)
                c = CustomPath(path,paint)
                array.add(c)
                myRefDraw?.push()?.setValue((array))

            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                path.lineTo(event.x, event.y)
                invalidate()

            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {


            }
        }
        return true
    }

    init {
        paint.color = Color.BLACK
        paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        paint.strokeWidth = 12f
        paint.strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND;
        paint.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND;



        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRefDraw = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("pathDraw");
        

    }

}```
````

and

````
class CustomPath(path: android.graphics.Path, paint: android.graphics.Paint){
    private var path: Path
    private var paint: Paint

    init {
        this.paint = paint
        this.path = path

    }

    fun setPath(path:Path){
        this.path = path
    }
    fun getPath(): Path {
        return this.path
    }

    fun setPaint(paint:Paint){
        this.path = path
    }
    fun getPaint(): Paint {
        return this.paint
    }

}```
````

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can help you.

Comment: I eddited the post with some code @Code-Apprentice

Comment: It's stll not clear where, in all that code, your push() occurs.  The question should contain enough information that someone can easily reproduce the issue.

Comment: my mistake, the push occurs on the class canvas view, in the onTouchEvent action_down @DougStevenson

Comment: The error message might be misleading. Are `android.graphics.Path` and `android.graphics.Paint` serializable?

Comment: I don't think so, atleast I get this error "android.graphics.Path cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable" when i try to cast them as Serializable @muratgu

Comment: Making them serializable is possible but with a bit of extra work. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919740/how-to-serialize-an-object-of-android-graphics-path/8127953#8127953