# Serialize/Deserialize "androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Path"

Tags: android, serialization, android-jetpack-compose, deserialization

*Note: This isn't a duplicate of [how to serialize an object of android.graphics.Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919740/how-to-serialize-an-object-of-android-graphics-path/6643686#6643686) because `androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Path` and `android.graphics.Path` are different.*

I'm trying to save and load a user drawing based on compose graphics `Path` interface, which internally creates an `AndroidPath` class. I've looked all over the Internet and most suggestions are for `android.graphics.Path` which doesn't implement some functions like `translate(offset: Offset)`.
The question is how do I convert a path to string and vice versa. I've found a way to make a path from a string using `androidx.core.graphics.PathParser.createPathFromPathData(pathData)` though I'm still not sure if it works with `AndroidPath`. Here's the full drawing code in case it helps:

```kotlin
// Serialization / Deserialization fully implemented for this type.
data class PathProperties(
    var strokeWidth: Float = 10f,
    var color: Color = Color.Black,
    var alpha: Float = 1f,
    var strokeCap: StrokeCap = StrokeCap.Round,
    var strokeJoin: StrokeJoin = StrokeJoin.Round,
    var eraseMode: Boolean = false
)

data class DrawingPath(val path: Path, val properties: PathProperties)
```

Jetpack Compose code:

```kotlin
val drawModifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(top = 12.dp)
                        .shadow(1.dp)
                        .height(375.dp)
                        .clipToBounds()
                        .background(Color.White)
                        .dragMotionEvent(
                            onDragStart = { pointerInputChange ->
                                motionEvent = MotionEvent.Down
                                currentPosition = pointerInputChange.position
                                pointerInputChange.consumeDownChange()

                            },
                            onDrag = { pointerInputChange ->
                                motionEvent = MotionEvent.Move
                                currentPosition = pointerInputChange.position

                                if (drawMode == DrawMode.Touch) {
                                    val change = pointerInputChange.positionChange()
                                    paths.forEach { entry ->
                                        val path: Path = entry.path
                                        path.translate(change)
                                    }
                                    currentPath.translate(change)
                                }
                                pointerInputChange.consumePositionChange()

                            },
                            onDragEnd = { pointerInputChange ->
                                motionEvent = MotionEvent.Up
                                pointerInputChange.consumeDownChange()
                            }
                        )

                    Canvas(modifier = drawModifier) {
                        when (motionEvent) {
                            MotionEvent.Down -> {
                                if (drawMode != DrawMode.Touch) {
                                    currentPath.moveTo(currentPosition.x, currentPosition.y)
                                }

                                previousPosition = currentPosition

                            }
                            MotionEvent.Move -> {

                                if (drawMode != DrawMode.Touch) {
                                    currentPath.quadraticBezierTo(
                                        previousPosition.x,
                                        previousPosition.y,
                                        (previousPosition.x + currentPosition.x) / 2,
                                        (previousPosition.y + currentPosition.y) / 2

                                    )
                                }

                                previousPosition = currentPosition
                            }

                            MotionEvent.Up -> {
                                if (drawMode != DrawMode.Touch) {
                                    currentPath.lineTo(currentPosition.x, currentPosition.y)

                                    // Pointer is up save current path
                                    // paths[currentPath] = currentPathProperty
                                    paths.add(DrawingPath(currentPath, currentPathProperty))

                                    // Since paths are keys for map, use new one for each key
                                    // and have separate path for each down-move-up gesture cycle
                                    currentPath = Path()

                                    // Create new instance of path properties to have new path and properties
                                    // only for the one currently being drawn
                                    currentPathProperty = PathProperties(
                                        strokeWidth = currentPathProperty.strokeWidth,
                                        color = currentPathProperty.color,
                                        strokeCap = currentPathProperty.strokeCap,
                                        strokeJoin = currentPathProperty.strokeJoin,
                                        eraseMode = currentPathProperty.eraseMode
                                    )
                                }

                                // Since new path is drawn no need to store paths to undone
                                pathsUndone.clear()

                                // If we leave this state at MotionEvent.Up it causes current path to draw
                                // line from (0,0) if this composable recomposes when draw mode is changed
                                currentPosition = Offset.Unspecified
                                previousPosition = currentPosition
                                motionEvent = MotionEvent.Idle
                            }
                            else -> Unit
                        }

                        with(drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas) {

                            val checkPoint = saveLayer(null, null)

                            paths.forEach {

                                val path = it.path
                                val property = it.properties

                                if (!property.eraseMode) {
                                    drawPath(
                                        color = property.color,
                                        path = path,
                                        style = Stroke(
                                            width = property.strokeWidth,
                                            cap = property.strokeCap,
                                            join = property.strokeJoin
                                        )
                                    )
                                } else {

                                    // Source
                                    drawPath(
                                        color = Color.Transparent,
                                        path = path,
                                        style = Stroke(
                                            width = currentPathProperty.strokeWidth,
                                            cap = currentPathProperty.strokeCap,
                                            join = currentPathProperty.strokeJoin
                                        ),
                                        blendMode = BlendMode.Clear
                                    )
                                }
                            }

                            if (motionEvent != MotionEvent.Idle) {

                                if (!currentPathProperty.eraseMode) {
                                    drawPath(
                                        color = currentPathProperty.color,
                                        path = currentPath,
                                        style = Stroke(
                                            width = currentPathProperty.strokeWidth,
                                            cap = currentPathProperty.strokeCap,
                                            join = currentPathProperty.strokeJoin
                                        )
                                    )
                                } else {
                                    drawPath(
                                        color = Color.Transparent,
                                        path = currentPath,
                                        style = Stroke(
                                            width = currentPathProperty.strokeWidth,
                                            cap = currentPathProperty.strokeCap,
                                            join = currentPathProperty.strokeJoin
                                        ),
                                        blendMode = BlendMode.Clear
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                            restoreToCount(checkPoint)
                        }
                    }
```